# Express session sometime lost the session without logout [mobile app]

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I used express-session for my Node.js application with these options

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysecret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
      expires: new Date(253402300000000)
    }
  })
);
```

and sometime when I update the mobile app due to changes the session got lost and I have to logout and login again.